# There are two buttons and you need to change them alternately

Tags: reactjs

I have two buttons. I can change its color by clicking on one button. And when you click on another button, change its color as well, and return the old color to the first button. Something like toggle. How can I implement such functionality in a react applicatio.

```
const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false);
  const toggleIt = () => {
    setToggle(!toggle);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={toggleIt}>Button1</button>
      <button onClick={toggleIt}>Button2</button>
)
```

Comment: Do both buttons need to chage color on click, or only the clicked one?

Comment: What have you tried? SO isn't a free coding service.

Comment: @Jovana Only the one I clicked on. And remove the color from the other active button

Answer (score 0):

somthing like this ([codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-river-t18zk7?file=/src/App.js)),

```
import classNames from "classnames";
import { useCallback, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false);
  const toggleIt = useCallback(() => {
    setToggle((toggle) => !toggle);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={toggleIt}
        className={classNames({
          "btn-act": toggle
        })}
      >
        Btn A
      </button>
      <button
        onClick={toggleIt}
        className={classNames({
          "btn-act": !toggle
        })}
      >
        Btn B
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Ideally we shouldn't have to use an external package to solve this problem (can you write an answer that does not rely on `classnames`).

Answer (score 0):

```
    const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false);
    const toggleIt = () => {
       setToggle(!toggle);
    };
    
    return ( 
       <div>
           <button onClick={toggleIt} style={toggle ? {color: "blue"} : {color: "red"}}</button>
           <button onClick={toggleIt} style={toggle ? {color: "pink"} : {color: "purple"}}</button>
       </div>
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

### Background

You can use the `useEffect()` hook to accomplish this feature depending on the button pressed.  Just hold two states and flip them each time a different button is pressed, and with those two states you can use two separate functions to handle the `onClick()`'s.

The `useEffect()` hook automatically re-renders the component once any of the items in the dependency array at the end change, which will happen depending on the button pressed.

You can also directly set `true`/`false` values on your state variables with the second value that returns from `useState()`, and those state variables will automatically have their states updated without you manually assigning them.

There is very likely a better, more efficient way of doing it, but this is just a general guideline, if you will.

### This is the code

```
const [toggleOne, setToggleOne] = useState(false);
const [toggleTwo, setToggleTwo] = useState(true);

const toggleFirst = () => {
  setToggleOne(true);
  setToggleTwo(false);
};

const toggleSecond = () => {
  setToggleOne(false);
  setToggleTwo(true);
};

useEffect(() => {
  if (toggleOne) {
    // Do something with first button pressed
  } else if (toggleTwo) {
    // Do something with second button pressed
  }
}, [toggleOne, toggleTwo]);

return (
  <div>
    <button onClick={toggleFirst}>Button1</button>
    <button onClick={toggleSecond}>Button2</button>
  </div>
);
```